# I am trying to link a subform using Combo box, i write the following code

Tags: ms-access-2016

```
Dim mydrawing As String 
mydrawing = "select * from tbl_welddata  where([Drawingno] = " & Me!CboDrawingno & ")" 
Me.tbl_welddatasubform.Form.RecordSource = mydrawing Me.tbl_welddatasubform.Form.Requery
```

I am getting an error message as;

> Data type mismatch error 3464

Every time when I debug it pointing to this line

```
Me.tbl_welddatasubform.Form.RecordSource = mydrawing
```

could some one help me to sort it.

Answer (score 0):

Put in a debug line, and study the output:

```
Dim mydrawing As String 

mydrawing = "select * from tbl_welddata where([Drawingno] = " & Me!CboDrawingno & ")" 
' If text, quotes are needed:
' mydrawing = "select * from tbl_welddata where([Drawingno] = '" & Me!CboDrawingno & "')" 
Debug.Print mydrawing

Me!tbl_welddatasubform.Form.RecordSource = mydrawing
```

A requery is not needed.

Can you apply the resulting *mydrawing* manually?

Is *Drawingno* a number, not text?

Is *tbl_welddatasubform* the name of the subform *control*?